# Fixing DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm working on a Ruby Sinatra app with Active Record and it gets this error message printed in the console with every HTTP call.

I couldn't find anywhere more information about this deprecation or how to fix it.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections! is deprecated. Please call the method directly on the connection handler; for example: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.clear_active_connections!`. (called from clear_active_connections! at /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:320)
```

Answer (score 0):

The sinatra-activerecord gem needs to be at least 2.0.27 to fix this particular deprecation warning

Answer (score -1):

Solved. Just needed to update the gem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).